# Jquery ParseInt does not work

Tags: jquery, concatenation, parseint

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
var totp=11;

var ids="";
for(var c=1;c < totp;c++){
 var rateid='input#'+'rate'+c;
 var qtyid='input#'+'qty'+c;
 var discid='input#'+'disc'+c;
 var surcid='input#'+'surc'+c;
 var totid='input#'+'tot'+c;
 var vatid='input#'+'vat'+c;
 
 ids = ids + rateid+","+qtyid+","+discid+","+surcid+","+vatid+",";
 var idsl=ids.replace(/,+$/,'');

 $(idsl).keyup(function(){
  calcTotal(totp);
 });
}
 // alert(idsl);

 
 $('#addProd').click(function(){
  
   $('#newProd').fadeIn('fast');
  
 });
 
});

function calcTotal(rate){
var ftotv=0;
var fvatamt=0;
for(var d=1;d < rate;d++){
   var rateid='input#'+'rate'+d;
   var qtyid='input#'+'qty'+d;
   var discid='input#'+'disc'+d;
   var surcid='input#'+'surc'+d;
   var totid='input#'+'tot'+d;
   var vatid='input#'+'vat'+d;

  
   var ratev=$(rateid).val();
   var qtyv =$(qtyid).val();
   var discv=$(discid).val();
   var surcv=$(surcid).val();
   //surcv=parseInt(surcv);
   var totv=ratev * qtyv;
//   alert(surcv);
   var vatamt=totv*5/100;
   var totd=totv-discv;
   var totv=totd + surcv;

   totv=parseInt(totv)+parseInt(vatamt);
  
   $(totid).val(totv);
   ftotv=ftotv+totv;

   $(vatid).val(vatamt);
   fvatamt=fvatamt+vatamt;
 }  

   $(ftotvat).val(fvatamt);
   $(ftotid).val(ftotv);
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .newProd {
    display: none
  }
</style>
<form action='generateinvoice' method='POST'>
<input type='hidden' name='category' value='<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: cat in <b>C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\mechelec\Admin\addsale.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
'>
<div style="margin:0 auto">
<div style='margin-left:0;text-align:left'>
<div style='margin-top:30px;text-align:left'>ORDER</div><div class='company' style='margin-top:-20px'><div>
      <h3>Company</h3>
      <p>
       <select name='CompanyId'><option value='3'>Silitech</option></select>
      </p></div><div><h3>Purchase Order No</h3><p><input type='text' name='PurchaseOrderNo' style='width:150px' required></div></p><div><h3>Mode Of Payment</h3><p><input type='text' name='ModeOfPayment' required></div></p><p style='clear:both'></p></div> <div>PRODUCT</div><div><input type='hidden' name='InvoiceNo' style='width:150px'></div><br>
</div>
<div class='product'>
<span id='addProd'>Add Item</span><table><tr><th style='width:25%;'>Product Name</th><th style='width:5%'>Quantity</th><th style='width:10%'>Unit</th><th style='width:10%'>Rate</th><th style='width:10%'>Discount</th><th style='width:10%'>Surcharge</th><th style='width:10%'>VAT</th><th style='width:15%'>Total</th></tr><tr> 
     <td>
      <select name='ProductId[]'><option value='14'>Annealing Furnace</option><option value='13'>Gold Melting Furnace</option><option value='12'></option><option value='11'></option></select>
     </td><td style='width:10%'><input type='text' name='Quantity[]' id='qty1' required></td><td style='width:10%'>
      <select name='Unit[]'><option value='Piece'>Piece</option><option value='Box'>Box</option><option value='Kg'>Kg</option></select>
     </td><td><input type='text' name='Rate[]' id='rate1'required></td><td><input type='text' name='Discount[]' id='disc1'></td><td><input type='number' name='Surcharge[]' id='surc1'></td><td><input type='text' name='VAT[]' id='vat1'></td><td><input type='text' name='Total[]' id='tot1'></td></tr><tr> 
     <td>
      <select name='ProductId[]'><option value='14'>Annealing Furnace</option><option value='13'>Gold Melting Furnace</option><option value='12'></option><option value='11'></option></select>
     </td><td style='width:10%'><input type='text' name='Quantity[]' id='qty2' required></td><td style='width:10%'>
      <select name='Unit[]'><option value='Piece'>Piece</option><option value='Box'>Box</option><option value='Kg'>Kg</option></select>
     </td><td><input type='text' name='Rate[]' id='rate2'required></td><td><input type='text' name='Discount[]' id='disc2'></td><td><input type='number' name='Surcharge[]' id='surc2'></td><td><input type='text' name='VAT[]' id='vat2'></td><td><input type='text' name='Total[]' id='tot2'></td></tr><tr> 
     <td>
      <select name='ProductId[]'><option value='14'>Annealing Furnace</option><option value='13'>Gold Melting Furnace</option><option value='12'></option><option value='11'></option></select>
     </td><td style='width:10%'><input type='text' name='Quantity[]' id='qty3' required></td><td style='width:10%'>
      <select name='Unit[]'><option value='Piece'>Piece</option><option value='Box'>Box</option><option value='Kg'>Kg</option></select>
     </td><td><input type='text' name='Rate[]' id='rate3'required></td><td><input type='text' name='Discount[]' id='disc3'></td><td><input type='number' name='Surcharge[]' id='surc3'></td><td><input type='text' name='VAT[]' id='vat3'></td><td><input type='text' name='Total[]' id='tot3'></td></tr><tr> 
     <td>
      <select name='ProductId[]'><option value='14'>Annealing Furnace</option><option value='13'>Gold Melting Furnace</option><option value='12'></option><option value='11'></option></select>
     </td><td style='width:10%'><input type='text' name='Quantity[]' id='qty4' required></td><td style='width:10%'>
      <select name='Unit[]'><option value='Piece'>Piece</option><option value='Box'>Box</option><option value='Kg'>Kg</option></select>
     </td><td><input type='text' name='Rate[]' id='rate4'required></td><td><input type='text' name='Discount[]' id='disc4'></td><td><input type='number' name='Surcharge[]' id='surc4'></td><td><input type='text' name='VAT[]' id='vat4'></td><td><input type='text' name='Total[]' id='tot4'></td></tr><tr> 
     <td>
      <select name='ProductId[]'><option value='14'>Annealing Furnace</option><option value='13'>Gold Melting Furnace</option><option value='12'></option><option value='11'></option></select>
     </td><td style='width:10%'><input type='text' name='Quantity[]' id='qty5' required></td><td style='width:10%'>
      <select name='Unit[]'><option value='Piece'>Piece</option><option value='Box'>Box</option><option value='Kg'>Kg</option></select>
     </td><td><input type='text' name='Rate[]' id='rate5'required></td><td><input type='text' name='Discount[]' id='disc5'></td><td><input type='number' name='Surcharge[]' id='surc5'></td><td><input type='text' name='VAT[]' id='vat5'></td><td><input type='text' name='Total[]' id='tot5'></td></tr><tr> 
     <td>
      <select name='ProductId[]'><option value='14'>Annealing Furnace</option><option value='13'>Gold Melting Furnace</option><option value='12'></option><option value='11'></option></select>
     </td><td style='width:10%'><input type='text' name='Quantity[]' id='qty6' required></td><td style='width:10%'>
      <select name='Unit[]'><option value='Piece'>Piece</option><option value='Box'>Box</option><option value='Kg'>Kg</option></select>
     </td><td><input type='text' name='Rate[]' id='rate6'required></td><td><input type='text' name='Discount[]' id='disc6'></td><td><input type='number' name='Surcharge[]' id='surc6'></td><td><input type='text' name='VAT[]' id='vat6'></td><td><input type='text' name='Total[]' id='tot6'></td></tr><tr> 
     <td>
      <select name='ProductId[]'><option value='14'>Annealing Furnace</option><option value='13'>Gold Melting Furnace</option><option value='12'></option><option value='11'></option></select>
     </td><td style='width:10%'><input type='text' name='Quantity[]' id='qty7' required></td><td style='width:10%'>
      <select name='Unit[]'><option value='Piece'>Piece</option><option value='Box'>Box</option><option value='Kg'>Kg</option></select>
     </td><td><input type='text' name='Rate[]' id='rate7'required></td><td><input type='text' name='Discount[]' id='disc7'></td><td><input type='number' name='Surcharge[]' id='surc7'></td><td><input type='text' name='VAT[]' id='vat7'></td><td><input type='text' name='Total[]' id='tot7'></td></tr><tr> 
     <td>
      <select name='ProductId[]'><option value='14'>Annealing Furnace</option><option value='13'>Gold Melting Furnace</option><option value='12'></option><option value='11'></option></select>
     </td><td style='width:10%'><input type='text' name='Quantity[]' id='qty8' required></td><td style='width:10%'>
      <select name='Unit[]'><option value='Piece'>Piece</option><option value='Box'>Box</option><option value='Kg'>Kg</option></select>
     </td><td><input type='text' name='Rate[]' id='rate8'required></td><td><input type='text' name='Discount[]' id='disc8'></td><td><input type='number' name='Surcharge[]' id='surc8'></td><td><input type='text' name='VAT[]' id='vat8'></td><td><input type='text' name='Total[]' id='tot8'></td></tr><tr> 
     <td>
      <select name='ProductId[]'><option value='14'>Annealing Furnace</option><option value='13'>Gold Melting Furnace</option><option value='12'></option><option value='11'></option></select>
     </td><td style='width:10%'><input type='text' name='Quantity[]' id='qty9' required></td><td style='width:10%'>
      <select name='Unit[]'><option value='Piece'>Piece</option><option value='Box'>Box</option><option value='Kg'>Kg</option></select>
     </td><td><input type='text' name='Rate[]' id='rate9'required></td><td><input type='text' name='Discount[]' id='disc9'></td><td><input type='number' name='Surcharge[]' id='surc9'></td><td><input type='text' name='VAT[]' id='vat9'></td><td><input type='text' name='Total[]' id='tot9'></td></tr><tr> 
     <td>
      <select name='ProductId[]'><option value='14'>Annealing Furnace</option><option value='13'>Gold Melting Furnace</option><option value='12'></option><option value='11'></option></select>
     </td><td style='width:10%'><input type='text' name='Quantity[]' id='qty10' required></td><td style='width:10%'>
      <select name='Unit[]'><option value='Piece'>Piece</option><option value='Box'>Box</option><option value='Kg'>Kg</option></select>
     </td><td><input type='text' name='Rate[]' id='rate10'required></td><td><input type='text' name='Discount[]' id='disc10'></td><td><input type='number' name='Surcharge[]' id='surc10'></td><td><input type='text' name='VAT[]' id='vat10'></td><td><input type='text' name='Total[]' id='tot10'></td></tr><tr><td colspan='6'>Total</td><td><input type='text' name='ftotvat' id='ftotvat'></td><td><input type='text' name='ftotc' id='ftotid'></td></tr></table></div><div style='margin-top:20px;text-align:left'>DELIVERY</div><div class='challan'><div><h3>Delivery Challan No</h3><p><input type='text' name='DeliveryChallanNo' style='width:150px' required></p></div><div><h3>Destination</h3><p><input type='text' name='Destination' style='width:150px' required></p></div><div><h3>Dispatch Through</h3><p><input type='text' name='DispatchThrough' style='width:150px' required></p></div><p style='clear:both'></p></div><div><h3>Remarks</h3><div><textarea style='width:100%;height:100px' name='Remarks' required></textarea></div></div></div>
  <input type='submit' name='addsub'></form>
```

I am creating an invoice with columns of rate, quantity, VAT (tax), discount and Surcharge with 10 rows in the table.

When I make an input in each column, it has to calculate the final total at the end of the row.

Everything works fine except the $(surcid) as shown in the snippet which is the id of the input field for Surcharge

I have checked all possible FAQs on this but still getting stuck somewhere.

All variables calculate as expected. Except for surcv.

It gets concatenated.

What is wrong here ?

Comment: What should be `$(surcid)`?

Comment: `$(surcid)` matches which type of HTML element? And so, what returns `$(surcid).val()`?!...

Comment: Include some HTML as it's relevant here, preferably make a snippet.  See [mcve]

Comment: I have edited the question and added the HTML and more JS. Hoping somebody can help.

Comment: Please show the generated HTML, not the PHP code (right click-->view page source).

Comment: @jjj it view page source is quite long. Can I post it here or will I be reorimanded for that ?

Comment: ... not *all* of it, just the relevant part, the same part you now have as PHP code.

Comment: @jjj have added the runnable snippet

Comment: @freedomn-m please check the runnable snippet i have added

Comment: @A.Wolff $(surcid) is number type and is supposed to return a number

Comment: @panther $(surcid) is the value of surcharge column which is number type

Comment: @user3526204: uhhh. Sorry, if anyone doesn't know how the hell looks, there is an example.

Comment: @panther can you guide me which way I have to look ?

Comment: @user3526204: sorry, when I saw st. like `for(var c=1;c < rate;c++){var ratec='rate'+c; ...` I've no reason to debug the rest of your code.

Comment: @panther I am a novice at JS / JQUERY.... would be greatly obliged if you could tell me how to get surcid be calculated as a number like all other variables are getting calculated...

Comment: I am at my wits end from last two days...just figuring this out

Comment: Way too much code to wade through, have a read of [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All variables calculate as expected. Except for surcv. It gets concatenated.

The issue is that `.val()` returns a string, as shown in this snippet:

```js
var x=$("#in").val();
console.log(x === "1")
console.log(x === 1)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='number' id='in' value="1"/>
```

If you use `+` on any value and a string, you get a string, eg:

```
var x = 1 + "2"
x==="12"
```

you fix this by converting the `.val()` to a number, there are many ways, including:

```js
console.log(parseInt($("#num").val(), 10) === 1)
console.log(($("#num").val() * 1) === 1)
console.log(($("#num").val() - 0) === 1)
console.log(~~$("#num").val() === 1)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="num" type="number" value="1"/>
```

(my personal preference is to use `* 1` as too many people miss the ,10 on parseInt)

In fact, your code does this already, just after it's already concatenated the string, you just need to move this to when you read the value:

Relevant code from the question:

```
        var ratev=$(rateid).val() * 1;
        var qtyv =$(qtyid).val() * 1;
        var discv=$(discid).val() * 1;
        var surcv=$(surcid).val() * 1;

        // All the above are now numbers, so can be manipulated fine.

        var totv=ratev * qtyv;
        var vatamt=totv * 5 / 100;
        var totd=totv - discv;
        var totv=totd + surcv;

        $(totid).val(totv);
```

Your other values were working fine as they were manipulated as numbers (`*` / `/` / `-`) while `+` will manipulate as as a string as per above.

Comment: Thanks tons and tons freedomn-m !!! You opened a plethora of information to me !  This is real effort seen at SO to address an issue after a long time ! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the origin of the problem. But I have found the problem and the solution. I found that the variable $(surcv) was outputting blank. So I just  added

> if(surcv===''){surcv=0;}

This solved my issue. Now the calculation is perfect.

Anyway, thanks to all those who put in efforts to help me.